# Extending python with C: trying to swap list elements

Tags: python-c-api

I am to build a C module for Python 3.7, that swaps two list elements. 
Here is my code, where indexes of two elements and list are read:

```
static PyObject *st_change(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
  PyObject *pList;
  PyObject *tmp1;
  PyObject *tmp2;
  int i,j;
  Py_ssize_t n;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!ll", &PyList_Type, &pList,&i,&j)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "parameters are wrong.");
    return NULL;
    }

  n = PyList_Size(pList);
  tmp1 = PyList_GetItem(pList,i);       
  tmp2 = PyList_GetItem(pList,j);
  PyList_SetItem(pList,i,tmp2);
  PyList_SetItem(pList,j,tmp1);
  Py_INCREF(pList);

  return pList;
}
```

This works for one-dimensional lists, but when I try to swap elements in list of lists, Python shuts down. 
For example, when a call

```
my_module.st_change([1,2,3],0,1)
```

the result is

```
[2,1,3]
```

and when I call

```
my_module.st_change([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],0,1)
```

python shell restsarts

I am completely new to C Python API, so would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: It looks OK to me (although it's missing any error checking - you don't know that `i` and `j` are greater than `0` and less than `n` for example. Obviously we can't comment about why your list of list code shuts down because you don't show it.

Comment: Thanks, i've added example

Comment: Ah I'd misunderstood. I'd thought you were using different C code. The example is helpful though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're losing a reference to `tmp1`. [`PyList_SetItem` discards a reference to the item already in that position](https://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/list.html?highlight=m), so when you do `PyList_SetItem(pList,i,tmp2);` you `tmp1` gets decreffed and probably deallocated. You get away with it for `int` because there are typically lots of references to small int values.

Before the calls to `PyList_SetItem` add `Py_INCREF(tmp1); Py_INCREF(tmp2);`